# Issue installing Debian on Thinkpad P51

Tags: debian, thinkpad

I'm trying to install Debian on my Thinkpad P51 which has Windows 10 preinstalled. I'm able to access the Debian installation menu just fine when I get to the boot menu. But when I click install, I just get a black screen.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you choose correct iso file? Check your boot media, try to boot it as live OS.

Comment: @Biswa I selected the entire debian download to be burnt onto my usb

Comment: Did you use graphical install or just install option?

Answer (score 1):

I had to go into the BIOS and disable secure boot and change the graphics mode from 'hybrid' to 'discrete'. As a side note, I also had issues with the video drivers in debian 9, but they seem to be fixed in debian 10.